# VirtualBox vs. Sandboxie - Multiple Instance of Application

Tags: virtualbox, multiple-instances, sandboxie

I am trying to run the same application multiple instances on one machine. Some applications does not allow multiple instance, so I figure I will use a virtual machine or something along that line to achieve my goal. (To be specific, the application I want to run is a IM application and does not allow more than one instance, and if possible, I also would like to run a second instance of a game)

After doing some research, I found 2 possible ways. (I know there might be more, but the 2 are the ones I look into more)

1. By using **VirtualBox** (https://www.virtualbox.org/), I can create another Desktop (or OS) and run a second instance of the application on it.
2. Run a second instance of the application using **Sandboxie** (http://www.sandboxie.com/)

**My question is:** Is there a significant advantage of using one over another? Or is there a even better solution to achieve my goal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Running virtualbox or any virtual machine will use more memory than something like sandboxes. However I believe that you are required to have the paid version of sandboxie to run multiple instances.

Comment: Also it depends on how the program is detecting if multiple programs are running, sandboxie won't let the program write changes out but it still may be able to do things like scan the names of programs that are currently open.

Comment: @Hans For the free version of Sandboxie, can I run a second instance of IM and second instance of game at the same time? I know I probably won't be able to run third or fourth instance of one app, but can I run 2nd instance of multiple different app? And from what I'm understanding, using Sandboxie will be better than VirtualBox in my case right?

Comment: I have tested just now, and yes you can run one instance directly and one in the sandbox with the default settings. I tested pidgin and it worked correctly, however skype would not let another instance be usable on the same computer. And yes, sandboxie would likely be preferable as it would consume less ram and have less overhead than a virtual machine.

Answer (score 0):

How many user accounts do you have, and have many do you need?

I'm wondering if the tidiest/easiest method by be employing the run as command, passing user credentials.

This way, each user's application data should be correctly managed in their (correlating) userdata/appdata/programdata folders... depends on THE APP, of course :)

IF the program is depending on a system services, I don't think Sandboxie will be of assistance (I opted for Office 2010 over Office'13, sandboxed, for this very reason)...

Chrome is the exceptional exception to the rule... looking at running --incognito (just to drop extensions - I'm an app monster - and allow for a QUICKLAUNCH, until my (multiple) chrome user profiles are correctly configured...)

back to the "system service"dependent apps... Have you tried running multiple instances of vbox? This SHOULD work...